# Can I physically swap keys on a chicklet keyboard, without causing any damage to the keys or keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

I have a GT780DX and I'd like to use AutoHotKey to switch a few key functions, but also swap the keys so that I don't get confused.

Can I physically swap keys on a chicklet keyboard, without causing any damage to the keys or keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, it depends on the keyboard. Some chicklet keyboards have separate caps for each key, in which case it's easy enough to open the case and switch the caps around. Some (like certain Lenovo models) have the whole keyboard wired as a single piece. Opening it means playing with wires (and definitely voiding your warranty).

In the case of your laptop, correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like it's a backlit keyboard. In this cae, I'm not sure you want to mess with it, unless you know for sure what you're doing and how to put it back.

My advice: if you're looking for a language-specific keyboard (like European or Latin key order), most manufacturers have such items and then you can replace the whole unit piecemeal.

Comment: no, I don't want a new language. I just want to swap a couple keys.

Comment: no, I can see the keyboard is not a single piece.

Comment: then go ahead and change the keys

Answer (score 0):

You could order some custom keyboard stickers.

Comment: This doesn't address the question at hand.  The question is referring to the physical keys.

Comment: Plus it is a backlit keyboard, so the keyboard stickers will not work.